# yum translation of rpm -Uvh

Tags: yum, rpm

I'm trying to understand what `yum` version of `rpm -Uvh` is. I found [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/425801/rpm-uvh-yum-install) question about that command and `yum`, but it doesn't have what I'm looking for. Looking at `--help`, would this be the equivalent of `-Uvh`?

```
$ yum -v update <package>
```

I'm using `yum 3.2.22`

Comment: Your Q makes little sense. These 2 tools serve very different purposes. `-Uvh` does an update, is verbose, and shows hashmarks when processing a file. YUM does hashmarks by default, `update` will update a particular package from the repo it was installed, and `-v` will make YUM verbose, similar to the `-v` in RPM.

Comment: @slm Isn't your comment actually an affirmative answer to the Q that "makes little sense"?

Comment: @TAFKA'goldilocks' - perhaps, but then what was the Q?

Answer (score 3):

Yum and RPM are complementary package managers.

**Install Package**

You can install a package with RPM like so

```
rpm -Uvh foo.rpm
```

You can install a package with YUM like so:

```
yum install foo
```

An explanation of rpm flags:

```
-i # Install, (will throw an error if already installed)
-U # Update (or install if not present), usually preferred over -i 
-v # verbose
-h # hash, basically just shows a pretty progress bar
```

**Upgrade Package**

You can upgrade a package with RPM the same way as installing packages

```
rpm -Uvh foo.rpm
```

You can upgrade a package with YUM like so:

```
yum update foo
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no real equivalent. However, if you do try to install some software and an older version already exists, you SHOULD be prompted to update it.

Comment: Is the syntax above correct?

Comment: Try and see? Please read the rules of this site.